# What is the proper way to periodically call web API from the same hosted web site

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

We developed web API hosted in IIS. We want to call certain APIs ourselves periodically. Ideally for simplicity of setup we want to have that code that calls API periodically also to be inside of this API. What is the best solution?

Currently we considering starting a thread in side of API to call it on timer.

Comment: maybe should look to SignalR ?

Comment: Also you can look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) jobs. You can create scheduler with some period to run tasks

Comment: AFAIK signalR is used to callback browser side code. What we want is to call server code from server.

Comment: I don't know real purpose of this calls, but if you don't have a client, you can use Quartz. We using it in our project for frequent tasks that should be done every 30 minutes

Comment: We had a similar requirement where we wanted to ping APIs regular interval of time, we build a outside client which takes input as endpoint to be called rather than having each API its own ping'er logic. For us going with a outside client worked as we were able to use the response for statistics and alerts , if you want you can do that or Quartz is a good option if you just want to do with each API.

Comment: take a look at this too... http://hangfire.io/